# nwjs menu stop working after window.location.href changed

Tags: menu, window, reload, nwjs

The menu stop working after I navigate to another url.
Here's now I added the menu:

```
var menu = new nw.Menu({
  type: 'menubar'
});
var menuItems = new nw.Menu();

menuItems.append(
  new nw.MenuItem({
    label: 'Surf Google',
    click: function() {
      window.location.href = 'https://google.com';
    }
  })
);

menuItems.append(
  new nw.MenuItem({
    label: 'Surf Github',
    click: function() {
      window.location.href = 'https://github.com';
    }
  })
);

menu.append(
  new nw.MenuItem({
    label: "The Menu",
    submenu: menuItems
  })
);

var w = nw.Window.get();

w.menu = menu
```

I've created a github branch to show this issue:
**https://github.com/wvary/nwjs-firewall-test/tree/tested-menu**

Here's how to reproduce this issue:

```
git clone https://github.com/wvary/nwjs-firewall-test.git
cd nwjs-firewall-test
git checkout tested-menu
npm run build
./dist/nwjs-firewall-test-1.0.0-mac-x64/nwjs-firewall-test.app/Contents/MacOS/nwjs
```

After the app launches, click on the Google menu item to surf the Google website.
Then click on the Github menu item.  It should surf Github, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an iframe which takes up the whole page and show it and set it's src attribute to the url you want to go to.

**EDIT:** you need to use a webview instead of an iframe

HTML:

```
<webview style="display:none; position:fixed; width: 100%; height:100%; bottom:0; right:0; top:0; left:0;" id="view_iframe"></webview>
```

JS:

```
var menu = new nw.Menu({
  type: 'menubar'
});
var menuItems = new nw.Menu();

menuItems.append(
  new nw.MenuItem({
    label: 'Surf Google',
    click: function() {
      document.getElementById("view_iframe").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("view_iframe").src = "https://google.com";
    }
  })
);

menuItems.append(
  new nw.MenuItem({
    label: 'Surf Github',
    click: function() {
      document.getElementById("view_iframe").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("view_iframe").src = "https://github.com";
    }
  })
);

menu.append(
  new nw.MenuItem({
    label: "The Menu",
    submenu: menuItems
  })
);

var w = nw.Window.get();

w.menu = menu
```

Comment: Is this the official approach or a workaround?  The default menu works fine.  Only customized menus become unusable.

Comment: This can't be the same.  There are some websites which can't handle iframes.

Comment: When you create a menu on the window if the page where you created the menu is replaced the menu will stop working. This works by instead of replacing the original page where the menu was created it will just display the page that you want to navigate to inside of an iframe.

Comment: Also with NWJS if inserting guest content you should always use an iframe anyway because of security reasons.

Comment: I tried to set the iframe src ot https://github.com and I got an error saying  iframe is not supported.  I see your point about the menu and it seems like a possible workaround, but what about websites not liking iframes?

Comment: I think you can use the webview tag I have tested this with github and it works. I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Perfect, this works for me.  I'm marking this as my answer.